# Having errors when accessing site on neocities but no errors when opening from visual studio code

Tags: html, visual-studio

I made a website for a school assignment and when I opened it in Chrome from Visual Studio Code, brilliant, no issues. So I uploaded everything onto Neocities to be graded and boom error 405 when submitting a form.

I don't know what to do. I cant find anyone facing similar issues.

```
<form name="myForm" onsubmit='validateForm()' method='post' action=ThankYouBuy.html> <!-- validateFrom() is a function from a javascript script i have listed in my header-->

<form action="/action_page.php"> <!--neocities says unexpected start tag -->
    <!-- NOTE i know it is 'img src' but i don't have enough reputation to actually type that -->
    <div class="icon-container">
        <'image src="https://www.merchantequip.com/image/logos=v|m|a|gw|apl|ssp|adp&height=32" alt="Merchant Equipment Store Credit Card Logos"/'>
    </div> <!-- neocities says Named entity expected. got none -->

</form> <!-- neocities says End tag seen to early, ignored -->

</form> <!-- neocities says unexpected end tag. ignored -->
```

What I'm trying to do is to, after having my Javascript script validate the form inputs, direct the user to a thank you page.

Comment: There is no `<image>` in HTML. You are probably looking for `<img>`.

Comment: Grammar & code formatting.

Answer (score 0):

i had the SAME problem. made a code in a test in freeCodeCamp and it worked, but when i tried to import it to neocities it didnt work.

try using this site: https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

its used to validate the code you write, using it i found out my mistakes